# NodeJs running ImageMagick convert all images from directory

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

This is basic imagemagick setup for node.js that i came across lately. I understand that question i'm asking is very newbie but i'm new to node js and imagemagick and i wanted to try to make it dynamic. Current script bellow is cropping one specific file, is there a way to make it to apply conversion to all the files from directory `/before` and then output it to directory `/after` ? Also the operation i want to do for all the images in directory is to apply watermark on each (crop operation in code is just from example).

```
var http = require("http");
var im = require("imagemagick"); 

var args = [
  "image.png",
  "-crop",
  "120x80+30+15",
  "output.png"
];

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  im.convert(args, function(err) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    res.end("Image crop complete");
  });

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by implementing foreach by all files itself.
Also you will need to install async module:

```
npm install async
```

Example code:

```
var async = require('async'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    im = require('imagemagick'),
    maxworkers = require('os').cpus().length,
    path = require('path');

module.exports = resize;

function resize(params) {
    var queue = async.queue(resizeimg, maxworkers);

    fs.readdir(params.src, function(err, files) {
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            queue.push({
                src: path.join(params.src, '/', file),
                dest: path.join(params.dest, '/', file),
                width: params.width,
                height: params.height
            })
        });
    });
}

function resizeimg(params, cb) {
    var imoptions = {
        srcPath: params.src,
        dstPath: params.dest
    };
    if (params.width !== undefined) imoptions.width = params.width;
    if (params.height !== undefined) imoptions.height = params.height
    im.resize(imoptions, cb);
}
```

Then in you code:

```
var http = require("http");
var resize = require("./resize");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    resize({
      src: '/source/folder',
      dest: '/destination/folder',
      width: 300
    });

}).listen(8080);
```